# In git-bash vi mode, insert mode, why is 'delete' mapped to 'esc' '3' instead of 'delete'?

Tags: windows, bash, vim, msysgit, git-bash

In git-bash vi mode, if you're not already in insert mode, hit i.

Now when you try to use delete you exit into command mode and the prompt shows  `(arg: 3)`

So it seems that `delete` is mapped to `esc` `3`

And how can it be restored to the normal delete key behaviour?

I've tried various combinations of the following maps in .inputrc to no avail.

```
set editing-mode vi
$if mode=vi
  set keymap vi-insert
  "\e[3~": delete-char
  "DEL": delete-char
$endif
```